# Creating a 2d array, one dimension not known at compile time

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

Two things going on I need clarification with: two dimensional array and an array whose length is determined at run time. The first length is unknown, the second is known to be two.

```
char** mapping = new char*[2];//2d array
mapping[2][0] = 'a';
```

This program crashes because of memory being written to that is not allocated to the array, how can I fix it? Could you please explain your answer.

Answer (score 3):

If only the first of the array sizes is a run-time value (and the rest are compile-time values), then you can allocate it in one shot. In your case, for run-time size `n`

```
char (*mapping)[2] = new char[n][2];
```

Access this array "as usual", i.e. as `mapping[i][j]`, where `i` is in `0..n-1` range and `j` is in `0..1` range.

However, unless you have some specific efficiency/layout requirements, it might be better idea to use `std::vector`.

Comment: In the sense of 2d array, what we need to do is crate a pointer array and point these each pointers to start point of the actual arrays. Normally I'm doing it like this `int** ary = new int*[sizeX];for(int i = 0; i < sizeX; ++i) {ary[i] = new int[sizeY];}`. Now I'm curios how it happens in one line of code `char (*mapping)[2] = new char[n][2];`.  could you kindly explain, how this happens for others information.

Comment: This is what I did but now I can't figure out how to write the return value in the functions signature since `n` isn't known until run time?

Comment: @Celeritas: What function's? You have to provide more details about what you are trying to do. If you want to return a pointer to this array (e.g. `mapping`) from a function, one way to go about it is to `typedef` the type first: `typedef char Char2[2]`. Then you can rewrite the above as `Char2 *mapping = new Char2[n]`. And then just use `Char2 *` as function return type and do `return mapping;`. (There are other ways to `typedef` this.) It is possible to do it without `typedef`, but the syntax for function return value will be very convoluted.

Comment: @AndreyT I started a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535256/how-to-return-a-2d-array-where-one-dimension-is-of-unknown-size/16594354?noredirect=1#16594354

Answer (score 0):

You need to write:

```
mapping[1] = new char(1);
mapping[1][0] = 'a';
```

Every row in the 2D array should be separately initialized and index starts from 0 and maximum available index is 1 but you try to access 3rd 1D array.

Answer (score -1):

Just do it like this and all your problems will be gone:

```
int size_x = 10, size_y = 20;
char* arr = new char[size_x*size_y];

char get(int x, int y) {
  return arr[x+y*size_x];
}

void set(int x, int y, char val) {
  arr[x+y*size_x]=val;
}
```